# Identifying the cause of defects in an H-Bridge by damaged transistors

Tags: transistors, h-bridge, troubleshooting

I am preparing a fishbone diagram for reactive maintenance to be used as evaluative approach and part of it is brainstorming possible causes to get contributing factors.

Consider the following H-bridge:

[image]

I am trying to identify the cause of defects in the H-bridge by pointing out damaged couple of transistors as follows:

1. Q1 and Q2 (or Q3 and Q4):

   a. control problem.

   b. one transistor is blown up and shorted causing the other to follow.
2. Q1 and Q4 (or Q2 and Q3):

   a. load short-circuited.
3. Q1 and Q3 (or Q2 and Q4):

   a. rare case, uknown reason.

Could you please help completing or correcting this list?

Comment: Which exactly happened?   If any are happening with any frequency, you have a problem with the design of your system for its application.  We do *specific* questions here, supported by their *actual context*, not broad and isolated generalities.

Comment: It does not concern a particular circuit but while troubleshooting some problems on h-bridges appeared and I am trying to analyse it since sometime just replacing the transistor without knowing the cause leads to repeated provlem.

Comment: The cause you need to worry about would be whatever caused the *initial failure*.  This needs more focus on an actual problem to be a question which can belong here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thank you for your comments. In fact, I am preparing a fishbone diagram for reactive maintenance to be used as evaluative approach and part of it is brainstorming possible causes to get contributing factors so I think it is appropriate to be discussed here.